# Windows 7 does not Boot after removing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, mbr

I had Windows 7 and ubuntu on my PC. Now I removed Ubuntu from Disk via Windows and restored original MBR oft Win7 via Installation disk. Now I tried to Boot thr PC. Following message: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible. Now I am trying to restore MBR again via Install disk but now I get this message. (Not 100% right, I translated it from German): This version of the systemrecoveryoption is not compatible with the Version you are trying to repair. Use a recoverydisk compatible with this Windows Version.
Need to reinstall or another way to fix?

Answer (score 1):

The following method completely rebuilds everything, you can use it from your favorite Windows Setup. Just use Shift-F10 to fire up a command prompt without going through unnecessary steps.

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

This installs a completely pristine Windows Boot Manager to c: and adds Windows to it. You may need to find the right drive letter first, though.